# Creating a new variable based on conditions in others variables in a data frame in R

Tags: r, function, loops

There are 100 delivery trucks and new trucks are added to the fleet regularly while the old trucks are removed regularly as well. A new truck takes 5 days to reach regular throughput like the current trucks as it's target is set to increase linearly in the first 5 days starting from 0.2 on day-1, 0.4 on day-2 to 1 in day-5. Once it reaches full potential in 5 days it's no longer called a new truck. Only old trucks are removed from the fleet. Here is what the data looks like and I want to calculate the column TrucksByPerformance based on other columns.I created nextweeknewtrucks column to make a function but it's not working as required. Below is the data,

```
**Day    trucks   newtrucks  nextweeknewtrucks  TrucksByPerformance**
Day1    100        NA             2               100.00

Day2    102         2            -1               100.40

Day3    101        -1             4                99.80

Day4    105         4            -2               101.80

Day5    103        -2             1               103.00

Day6    104         1             1               107.60

Day7    105         1             NA              111.40
```

I tried this and it's not working,

```
TrucksByPerformance = round(cumsum(1:5)/(5/nextweeknewtrucks) +trucks,2)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How do you know when an old truck will be removed?

Comment: Hi Allan, the assumption is negative values in the column 'newtrucks' means the number of trucks removed that day and the positive value implies number of trucks added to the fleet that day.